# MySQL update part of a whole string?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, variables

I store numeric variables in a string.  Like:165,37,0,0,21

Now i have to change only the last part but keep the rest the same. (in my example i need to change 21 to 0)

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Don't store values as a list in a string, store them individually in a separate table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: Is it always only the last part that changes? Or do you need to change some inner values too from time to time? If the later also occurs, normalize your data.

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, i have to change only the last part, in every rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sugest using regular expression for this, the below reg ex will find the number at the end of the string, including the last comma, and replace it with ',0'

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(column1 , ',[0-9]*$', ',0')
```

Answer (score -1):

REPLACE would be most ideal in this case:

```
UPDATE tbl_name 
SET 
field_name = REPLACE(field_name,
    string_to_find,  -- in your case 21
    string_to_replace  -- in your case 0 ) 
WHERE
<place condition if any e.g. the key to that record>;
```

Comment: This will not work if there are multiple 21's or numbers containing 21 like 211.